# SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object" (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I do not understand what went wrong when parsing file:

```
{ "t": -9.30, "p": 728.11, "h": 87.10 }
```

javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check() {
    $.get("http://....file.json", function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "success") {
            var json = JSON.parse(response);
            $("#temp").html(json.t + "&deg;");
            $("#pressure").html(json.p + " mm hg");
        }
        if (status == "error") {
            $("#temp").html("error");
        }
    });
}
```

I receive error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"
```

Comment: console.log(response); ?

Comment: you  don't need to parse

Comment: You already have an object, no need to parse it.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Most probably your `response` is already a JavaScript object and it not required to be parsed.

Remove the line `var json = JSON.parse(response);` and your code should work.

Comment: Than make a check if it is an object or use $.ajax and tell it what it is supposed to be....

Answer (score 12):

According to the jQuery docs on [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (which is what `$.get` uses internally):

> **dataType:** ...If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 **JSON will yield a JavaScript object**...)

Thus, your response is likely already an object. When you do `JSON.parse(response)`, you're really doing

```
JSON.parse("[object Object]")
```

because [`JSON.parse` coerces its argument to a string](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.2), and plain objects by default stringify to `[object Object]`. The initial `[` leads `JSON.parse` to expect an array, but it then chokes on the `object` token, which does not fit the JSON grammar.

Remove the `JSON.parse` line, because `response` is already parsed into an object by jQuery.