# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character, but on jsonlint works well

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to recive from ajax a json response, here where i ask for data and the operation the i make on response:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    dataType : "json",
    url: ea_map_ajaxurl,
    data: {
        action: 'get_markers_info',
        id : marker.id,
        ids_prodotti: marker.ids_prodotti,
        ids_owner: marker.ids_owner
    },
    success: function(data){
        response =  JSON.parse(data);

        $(response).each(function(){
            console.log(this.id);
        });
    }
});
```

This is the json response, that i have already tested with [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com) where it's valid but that i can't manage.

```
[
    {
        "id": "938",
        "post_title": "Cooperativa Arvaia",
        "indirizzo": "n.p.",
        "term_taxonomy_id": [
            "117",
            "190"
        ],
        "latitudine": "45",
        "longitudine": "11"
    },
    {
        "id": "1226",
        "post_title": "Prova inserimento",
        "indirizzo": "Via le mani dal naso, 1",
        "term_taxonomy_id": [
            "184"
        ],
        "latitudine": "44.634",
        "longitudine": "11"
    },
    {
        "id": "1257",
        "post_title": "Osteria Rovescio",
        "indirizzo": "Via Pietralata 41",
        "term_taxonomy_id": [
            "109"
        ],
        "latitudine": "45.123",
        "longitudine": "10.732"
    }
]
```

And this is the function where i create that json:

```
function getMarkersInfo() {
    global $wpdb;

    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $ids_prodotti=$_POST['ids_prodotti'];
    $ids_owner=$_POST['ids_owner'];

    $q=ea_db_get_marker_info($id,$ids_prodotti,$ids_owner);
    $infos=$wpdb->get_results($q, ARRAY_A);

    $json_info=Array();
    foreach ($infos as $info){
        if(! isset($json_info[$info['ID']])) {
            $json_info[$info['ID']]=Array(
                'id' => $info['ID'],
                'post_title' => $info['post_title']
            );
        }

        if($info['meta_key'] == 'ea_desc_indirizzo' && 
           !isset($json_info[$info['ID']]['indirizzo'])){
            $json_info[$info['ID']]['indirizzo']=$info['meta_value'];
        } elseif ($info['meta_key'] == 'ea_map_latitudine' && 
            !isset($json_info[$info['ID']]['latitudine'])) {
            $json_info[$info['ID']]['latitudine']=$info['meta_value'];
        } elseif ($info['meta_key'] == 'ea_map_longitudine' &&
            !isset($json_info[$info['ID']]['longitudine'])) {
            $json_info[$info['ID']]['longitudine']=$info['meta_value'];
        } 

        if (! isset($json_info[$info['ID']]['term_taxonomy_id']) ||
            ! in_array($info["term_taxonomy_id"],$json_info[$info['ID']]['term_taxonomy_id'])){
            $json_info[$info['ID']]['term_taxonomy_id'][]=$info["term_taxonomy_id"];
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($json_info);
    die();
}
```

Comment: dont need to parse it again...because you already set `dataType : "json",`

Comment: Why do you use JSON.parse(data); as data is alreay a valid json returned from server?

Comment: And are you sure it is what you think it is? `success: function(data){ console.log(data);`

Comment: change your question to a non-json datatype, and log exactly what came back from your script. it may LOOK fine in your browser, but there could be some non-printable/invisible characters pre-/post-pended throwing off the json.

Comment: @SSA: What comes from the server *does* need to be parsed. It's just that jQuery does it in the background as Pranav C Balan noted.

Comment: @MarcB how i can do that?

Comment: @jedi: don't bother, pranav was right. you're trying to decode an already-decoded json string.

Comment: @cookie monster: You are right. I phrased it wrong.

Comment: @jedi: Just get rid of the `JSON.parse` line altogether. jQuery is already doing that in the background. Just do `$.each(data, func...`. *(Notice that I'm not using `$(data).each(func...` since  you should be using the generic iterator.)*

Comment: @MarcB, you have right, removing datatype: "json" from the $.ajax settings and removing header('Content-Type: application/json') from the function where it generates the response. It's parse well. I think that JSON has stupid and undebuggable output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier “object” (anonymous function)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20660399/710446) -- you are attempting to `JSON.parse` an object, not a string

Comment: json is not stupid. it's essentially the right-hand side of a JS variable assignment. `var foo = blah`, `blah` is essentially JSON. json's syntax is a little stricter, but that's all it is.

Comment: @jedi: Why would you do that? Keep it the way it was. It isn't that the output is stupid... it's just that whatever you send gets converted `.toString()`, and an object ends up being converted to `[object Object]`, so *that's* what you were trying to parse.

Comment: @cookie-monster, there are a lot of person that waste time for stupid reason like that, it's beacause JSON don't help you with friendly message. It says SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character, if you have lose a "," or something other. For other languages there are better parser. I hope something for JSON too.

Comment: It seems likely that your question is a duplicate of the question I proposed; please let me know if the answer there does not solve your immediate problem. (If the answers there do solve this problem, but then you develop another, unrelated problem, please feel free to open a new question.)

Comment: @apsillers yes it solve

Comment: @jedi: I see what you're saying. They don't give very much context around the error. I agree that would be helpful.