# SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object" when trying to parse json

Tags: javascript, json, jsonparser

I'm getting errors when trying to parse a string to json

here is my String

```
{"location": " Antoine Vallasois Ave, Vacoas-Phoenix, England", "stopover":true}
```

and here is my javascript function

```html
function fillWaypoints(location){
 var ob =JSON.parse(location);
 ArrayWaypoints.push(ob)
 
}
```

Comment: `location` is probably already an object, not json, so no need to parse.

Comment: @Wreigh what do you mean ?

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660399/syntaxerror-json-parse-error-unexpected-identifier-object-anonymous-functio

Comment: You are probably not escaping the `"` character.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i'm escaping

Comment: @Wreigh  i've removed the parser and see what's im having  SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues here:

1. `location` is a keyword in JavaScript, you cannot pass that as parameter to a function.
2. `location` value `" Antoine Vallasois Ave, Vacoas-Phoenix, England", "stopover":true` is not a valid JSON, so it will give you an error.
3. You didn't declare `ArrayWaypoints`.

You can try the following way:

```js
var loc = {"location": " Antoine Vallasois Ave, Vacoas-Phoenix, England", "stopover":true}
var ArrayWaypoints = [];
function fillWaypoints(loc){
  loc.location.split(',').forEach(function(l){
    ArrayWaypoints.push(l.trim());
  });
}
fillWaypoints(loc);
console.log(ArrayWaypoints);
```

Comment: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'ArrayWaypoints.push')

Comment: @NickyLarson, what is not working? what is the output you are expecting? Did you run the snippet of my answer?

Comment: with my codes i'm getting  TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'ArrayWaypoints.push')

Comment: sorry it looks like I messed up something with array var ArrayWaypoints = [] , xD I've defined it as **var ArrayWaypoints = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('myArray'));**

Comment: @NickyLarson, you are most welcome. Great to know that you are able to get going.......thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please Note Here You are trying to parse Json.. You have to pass string in JSON.parse() function because JSON.parse can only parse string into json:-

```
var a = '{"location": " Antoine Vallasois Ave Vacoas-Phoenix England", "stopover":true}'

let ArrayWaypoints = [];

function fillWaypoints(location){
    var ob =JSON.parse(location);
    ArrayWaypoints.push(ob)

}
```