# Unexpected identifier "string" in Json even if the object is of correct type

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I'm trying to print all the contents in my **data**. I tried to check if my variable contains them with `console.log(data.responseText);` I got this:

```
string(3) "all"
[{"ID":"1","Nome":"Sony KD55XF8577","Prezzo":"999.99","Descrizione":"TV QLED 55","QTA":"3","Categoria":"1","Immagine":"KD55XF8577.jpg"},{"ID":"2","Nome":"Samsung QE49Q6FNATXZT","Prezzo":"699.99","Descrizione":"TV QLED 49'' ","QTA":"4","Categoria":"1","Immagine":"QE49Q6FNATXZT.jpg"},{"ID":"3","Nome":"LG 55SK8000PLB","Prezzo":"499.99","Descrizione":"SMART TV LED 55","QTA":"3","Categoria":"1","Immagine":"55SK8000PLB.jpg"}]
```

that are all the data in my database, so it is correct. The problem is that when I try to do `JSON.parse(data.responseText).forEach(` I get **JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "string"**, even if as you can see the data are in a correct format.

```
function printData(data){
    $("prodotti").innerHTML="";
    JSON.parse(data.responseText).forEach(
        function(element){
            $("prodotti").innerHTML += "<div class=prodotto id=prodotto"+element["ID"]+">" +
             "<img src=../prodotti/"+element["Immagine"]+">" +
             "<div class=nomeprod>"+element["Nome"]+"</div>" +
             "<div class=prezprod>"+element["Prezzo"]+"&euro;</div>" +
             "<div class=descprod>"+((element["Descrizione"].length > 47)? element["Descrizione"].substring(0, 47)+"...":element["Descrizione"])+"</div>" +
             "<div class=quanprod>rimasti: "+element["QTA"]+"</div></div>";
        }
    );
 }
```

EDIT: the array I get is in this format string(3) [{obj1}, {obj2}, {obj3}], so this is the right format for that JSON function, right?

EDIT2: this is how I generate the JSON. First of all I used this method:

```
function request(t){
    type = t;
    new Ajax.Request("../inventario/get_prodotti.php",
    {
        parameters: {
            type: t
        },
        dataType: "json",
        onSuccess: printData
    });
}
```

Here is the php function: ($categoria = "all")

```
function getProdotti($categoria){
    $db = databaseConnection();
    $db -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Prodotto";
    $rows = $db -> query($query);
    return $rows -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

getprodotti.php

```
    <?php
       header('Content-Type: application/json');
       include("../common/stock_functions.php");
       $type = $_POST['type'];
       var_dump($type);
       $rows = getProdotti($type);
   ?>
   <?= json_encode($rows); ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object" (anonymous function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660399/syntaxerror-json-parse-error-unexpected-identifier-object-anonymous-functio)

Comment: Just get rid of `var_dump($type);` obviously it's not returning valid JSON. Also why close then open PHP again?

Comment: And why not use jQuery `$.post()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your responseText

```
string(3) "all"
[{"ID":"1","Nome":"Sony KD55XF8577","Prezzo":"999.99","Descrizione":"TV QLED 55","QTA":"3","Categoria":"1","Immagine":"KD55XF8577.jpg"},{"ID":"2","Nome":"Samsung QE49Q6FNATXZT","Prezzo":"699.99","Descrizione":"TV QLED 49'' ","QTA":"4","Categoria":"1","Immagine":"QE49Q6FNATXZT.jpg"},{"ID":"3","Nome":"LG 55SK8000PLB","Prezzo":"499.99","Descrizione":"SMART TV LED 55","QTA":"3","Categoria":"1","Immagine":"55SK8000PLB.jpg"}]
```

is not a valid JSON object. You are expecting an array, so you json should look something like this (indented for clarity)

```
[
    {"ID":"1",....},
    {"ID":"2",....},
    {"ID":"3",....}
]
```

so without "all". The reason that `string(3) "all"` is outputted is because you are dumping the variable `$type`; remove that line and your output should be fine

Comment: This JSON is generated always by passing a category product as parameter (in this case "all"). Is there a way to convert that object into an array?

Comment: what backend technology are you using and how are you returning the data?

Comment: I'm gonna update the question with "get_prodotti.php"

Comment: Do you get an error now then? Is this local you're developing? It might be that you do not have the JSON extension installed....

Comment: If you do not have the JSON extension installed, either install it or fall back to writing out the JSON string yourself

Comment: "You are now just returning a database result, but you should model it to a proper json object" They are obviously already doing the code that is in your answer. The problem is the extra added at the beginning, they just need to not output it.

Comment: @miken32 he wasnt when first asking this question; check these comments

Comment: I didn't "just" downvote. I left a comment saying what was wrong with the answer, which is more than I need to do. Nowhere in your answer do you say to get rid of the `var_dump()` statement which is the obvious problem!

Comment: which is, like I already stated, added later on. Try answering this question without the sample code for get_prodotti.php...

Comment: Ok, why not edit your answer to suggest the real fix?

Comment: I sure will, but I'm not on StackOverflow 24/7 :)

Answer (score -2):

.forEach() works as Loop Iteration and Passed Argument must of data type Array so that it can be iterative. Check Data type of your argument data.responseText  what type of data it is. Based on that do the updation required.

Comment: Yes, as you can see from my console.log(data.responseText); the data I'm trying to parse is an array

Comment: in this case you need to use $.parseJSON(data.responseText) and then apply .foreach on it

Comment: "As of jQuery 3.0, $.parseJSON is deprecated. To parse JSON strings use the native JSON.parse method instead." from the JQuery website